# Cancel long running query or transaction in firebird

Tags: delphi, firebird

how can i safely abort/cancel currently running query/transaction. using gfix -shut may corrupt the database. i'm using delphi and firebird 2.5

Thanks in advance
Reynaldi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gfix can not corrupt database. It uses safe termination of running queries and rollbacks all active transactions.

You can cancel given query by executing DELETE FROM MON$STATEMENTS WHERE MON$STATEMENT_ID = ...

You can shut a whole attachment by executing DELETE FROM MON$CONNECTIONS WHERE CONNECTION_ID = ...

All queries should be run from parallel attachment.

Comment: i just ran a test by running long query and run gfix to shutdown the database. after i put the database back online i ran gfix validate and it reported corruption. tommorow i'll try to run another test and post the result.

Comment: how can i get the value of statement_id or connection_id? by parallel, do you mean open another connection?

Comment: If that indeed corrupts the database, then report it as a bug on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE

Comment: this is the error i get by running gfix -v -f. Number of database page error: 6147. I tested with 2 databases. 1 is an empty database i created just for testing purpose. this database does not report error. but when i test using production database (>200 mb) it report error

Comment: Could you please file a bug at the link in my previous comment, with reproduction steps etc.

Comment: i will. i'm just gonna check once more to make sure that this is a bug. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Next to the answer provided by Andrej, the Firebird 2.5 API also includes the [`fb_cancel_operation`](http://www.ib-aid.com/articles/item114) command which cancels all running actions on a database handle. You would need to check if your Delphi component supports this.